# onConfigurationChanged not getting called the first time

Tags: android, orientation

I've a problem trying to capture the `onConfigurationChanged` event. This is the scenario:

1. Activity A starts (listens to `onConfigurationChanged`)
2. Phone rotated to landscape mode (`onConfigurationChanged` being called). Start activity B.
3. Activity B starts (listens to `onConfigurationChanged`) (LANDSCAPE)
4. Activity B rotates back to portrait (`onBackPressed` event raised). Activity B is destroyed and A is called back.
5. Activity A resumes
6. Phone rotated to landscape mode. The `onConfigurationChanged` is not called this time.
7. Phone rotated to portrait mode. The `onConfigurationChanged` called.
8. Phone rotated to landscape mode. The `onConfigurationChanged` called.

Why step 6 don't call `onConfigurationChanged` event? it doesn't make sense at all. Do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you declared you want to listen for changes in your manifest?

Comment: Actually yes, and it works but just second time, the first time is not getting called

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I update UI `onResume()` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I still don't understand this behavior of android system, but you can use `onOrientationChanged` of `OrientationEventListener` instead of configuration change handling.

See this answer (example is not perfect but shows the way): https://stackoverflow.com/a/13844242/554281

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem and was stuck in this for more than a week. Then I have prepared a sample APP with tabHost and reproduced the same issue on the sample app. After playing around with that, I found that this is a bug of android's tabHost. So, I have migrated tabHost to FragmentTabHost and found the problem is gone.

### The simulation of the Issue with tabHost:

Let, there are two tab i.e A and B

#### Simulation 1 (Arise the bug)

1. Arrive on A in portrait mode
2. Go to B on portrait mode
3. Rotate B to landscape
4. Back to A on landscape mode.
5. Rotate A to portrait (onConfigChanged method of tabActivity gets fired. But  onConfigChanged of A activity doesn't get fired)

#### Simulation 2 (Works fine)

1. Arrive on A in portrait Mode
2. Go to B on portrait mode (continue rotating as you want, but stop on portrait mode)
3. Back to A on portrait mode.
4. Rotate A to landscape (both onConfigurationChanged method of tabActivity and A activity gets fired)

Summary: If you get back to the screen in the same orientation you got out, both onConfigurationChanged() will get called.