# onConfigurationChanged not called once setRequestedConfiguration has been used

Tags: android

I have set am activity to handle configuration changes and it works, meaning that `onConfigurationChanged()` is called when the orientation changes.

The activity has a button to explicitly change the orientation. When clicked, it called  `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT)`.

Then the orientation is irrevocably set and `onConfigurationChanged()` is not called anymore.

How can I change the orientation when the user clicks the button while not loosing the `onConfigurationChanged()` callback ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I solved it. I am aware it is reinventing the wheel but it meets my requirement and I did not find a proper way to handle this with standard sdk tools.

First, create an `OrientationManager` class that listen to orientation changes

```
public class OrientationManager extends OrientationEventListener{
private static final String TAG = OrientationManager.class.getName();

private int previousAngle;
private int previousOrientation;
private Context context;
private OrientationChangeListener orientationChangeListener;
private static OrientationManager instance;
private OrientationManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public static OrientationManager  getInstance(Context context){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new OrientationManager(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public int getOrientation(){
    return previousOrientation;
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation){
    this.previousOrientation = orientation;
}


@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    if (orientation == -1)
        return;
    if(previousOrientation == 0){
        previousOrientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientationChangeListener != null){
            orientationChangeListener.onOrientationChanged(previousOrientation);
        }           
    }
    if (previousOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE &&
            ((previousAngle > 10 && orientation <= 10) ||
            (previousAngle < 350 && previousAngle > 270 && orientation >= 350)) ){
        if (orientationChangeListener != null){
            orientationChangeListener.onOrientationChanged(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        previousOrientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    }

    if (previousOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT &&
            ((previousAngle <90 && orientation >= 90 && orientation <270) ||
            (previousAngle > 280 && orientation <= 280 && orientation > 180))   ){
        if (orientationChangeListener != null){
            orientationChangeListener.onOrientationChanged(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
        previousOrientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    }
    previousAngle = orientation;
}

public void setOrientationChangedListener(OrientationChangeListener l){
    this.orientationChangeListener = l;
}

public interface OrientationChangeListener{
    public void onOrientationChanged(int newOrientation);
}
}
```

Then in your activity implement `OrientationChangeListener` and override `onOrientationChanged()`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OrientationChangeListener{

    private OrientationManager orientationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        orientationManager = OrientationManager.getInstance(this);
        orientationManager.setOrientationChangedListener(this);

    }

@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(int newOrientation) {
    orientation = newOrientation;
    if (newOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        setLandscapeConfig();
    }else{
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setPortraitConfig();
    }
}
```

So I don't use `onConfigurationChanged` anymore but keep the following line in the Manifest:
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: Implement your solution but onOrientationChanged is never called when I rotate the device. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, must call orientationManager.enable() in activity constructor!

Answer (score 4):

Calling `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);` will reactivate `onConfigurationChanged`. You can set up a timer like this:

```
// Force orientation to portrait
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);

// Reactivate sensor orientation after delay
Timer mRestoreOrientation = new Timer();
mRestoreOrientation.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }
}, 2000);
```

We can only suppose the user will turn the device by himself to the forced orientation within the delay, and this can lead to bad user experience.

Comment: ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT)
```

This makes your onConfigurationChanged to stop working. If you want it to work, try adding this to your manifest within that activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

The screenSize attribute is only for API 13+ so if your below that, you don't need it

Comment: it's already in the manifest, otherwise onConfigurationChanged would not work at all

Answer (score 0):

> ..after many search this the right code mix that solve. enjoy!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);

OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new 
OrientationEventListener(getApplicationContext()) {
    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        boolean isPortrait = isPortrait(orientation);
        if (!isPortrait && savedOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            savedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
        } else if (isPortrait && savedOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            savedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
        }
    }
};
orientationEventListener.enable(); 
}

private int savedOrientation;
private boolean isPortrait(int orientation) 
{
    if (orientation < 45 || orientation > 315) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}    

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
  {
      currentOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
      // do what you need in landscape mode....
  }
  else if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
  {
        currentOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        // do what you need in portrait mode....
  }
}  

public void rotateScreenByUIButton() {
if (currentOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
else
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from the answer that was accepted five years ago?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the orientation back to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED, the the onConfiguration change will be called again

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)
->
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)
```